# I can't output the html structure I want with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a loop in my project through a JSON file. I retrieve the href and the src of the image from it. But I need to output this in a specific way which is as follows:

```
<li>
    <a href="link1_fromJSON.HTML" data-transition="slidedown">
        <img src="image_1_fromJSON.jpg"/>
        <h3> Menu1</h3>
    </a></li>
<li>
    <a href="link2_fromJSON.HTML" data-transition="slidedown">
       <img src="image_2_fromJSON.jpg"/>
       <h3> Menu2</h3>
   </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="link_3_fromJSON.HTML" data-transition="slidedown">
        <img src="image_3_fromJSON.jpg"/>
        <h3> Menu3</h3>
    </a>
<li>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(index, d){
$("<li>", { html:'<img src="' + d.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url + '" />' }).appendTo("#div1"); 
});
```

What I get with it is just a list of images within a div. I don't know how to get the result I want exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better served to post it to the DOM once,

```
var myNewStuff = "";
$.each(data.posts, function(index, d){
    myNewStuff = myNewStuff + "<li><img src='" + d.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url + "' /></li>";
});
$(myNewStuff).appendTo("#div1");
```

EDIT: try to put the href in without any definition, so I guess here:

```
$.each(data.posts, function(index, d){
    myNewStuff = myNewStuff + "<li><a data-transition='slidedown' href='" + d.myhref + "<img src='" + d.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url + "' /><h3> Menu" + index + "</a></li>";
});
$(myNewStuff).appendTo("#div1");
```

**ANSWER**

```
var myNewStuff = "";
$.each(data.posts, function(index, d){
    myNewStuff = myNewStuff + "<li><a data-transition='slidedown' href='" + d.slug + "'><img src='" + d.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url + "' /><h3> Menu" + index + "</li>";
        });
$(myNewStuff).appendTo("#div1");
```

Comment: I just changed two little things in your code and it worked! thank you so much!

Comment: @ERed: Perhaps you could tell us what those "two little things" were?

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = [
        {href: '/url1', img: 'img1.jpg', text: 'text1'},
        {href: '/url2', img: 'img2.jpg', text: 'text2'},
        {href: '/url3', img: 'img3.jpg', text: 'text3'},
        {href: '/url4', img: 'img4.jpg', text: 'text4'}
    ];

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var li = $('<li>');
        var h3 = $('<h3>').text(data[i].text);
        var im = $('<img/>').attr('src', data[i].img);
        var a  = $('<a>').attr('href', data[i].href).append(im).append(h3);

        $('#list').append(li.append(a));
    }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this..

```
$("ul").append("<li><a href='url-here'><img src="' + d.thumbnail_images.thumbnail.url + '" /></a></li>");
```

Comment: I get this error in your line : SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: if u have given ul an id or class mention it .sample:$("ul#ID")or$("ul.class")

Comment: The quotes in the string are totally messed up and it would throw a syntax error. Even after fixing the string you're just creating a list and then discarding it.